# Direction of induced EMF(and current) and Lorentz force direction?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is the right hand rule for the Lorentz force (given the current and magnetic field directions)and the direction of induced EMF the same?

Answer (score 1):

The right hand rule is used to find the direction of magnetic induction based on the source currents. This direction is purely conventional : the magnetic flux density does not have a physical direction by itself, you have to choose one (by the right hand rule, or by choosing a vectorial product).

The direction of induced EMF is physical. The induced currents flow in the opposite direction to the currents that created them. The right hand rule is valid if you consider the induced currents and the *reaction* magnetic field (the reaction field tends to reduce the source field, so they have opposite directions).

In conclusion, when studying the induced currents, you really have to understand the physics behind the system ; whereas the right hand rule only gives you the conventional (unphysical) direction of magnetic flux density.